# Onclick isn't being assigned at all and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with closures

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to assign the "onclick" for a javascript generated `<a>` element to some function, `loadfunction(project[j].getName(), project[j].getPath()).`

```
var projects = []; //Some array of classes in it

function loadProject(aName, aPath){
    //does some stuff
}

function assignOnclick(num){
    return function(){
        loadProject(projects[num].getName(), projects[num].getPath());
    };
}

for(var j = 0; j < projects.length; j++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(projects[j]);
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.title = projects[j].getName();
    a.href = "AProject.html";
    a.onclick = assignOnclick(j);
    div.appendChild(a)
    div.classList.add("project");
    document.getElementById("projcontainer").appendChild(div)
}
```

Ideally, this should set the onclick to call `loadProject()` with a defined parameter. The elements are generated and everything else in the code works, but they are not assigned any onclick function and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var projects = []; //Some array of classes in it

function loadProject(aName, aPath){
    //does some stuff
}

for(var j = 0; j < projects.length; j++){

     var div = document.createElement("div");
     var a = document.createElement("a");

     var linkText = document.createTextNode(projects[j]);

     a.appendChild(linkText);
     a.title = projects[j].getName();
     a.href = "AProject.html";

     a.setAttribute('data-name', projects[j].getName());
     a.setAttribute('data-path', projects[j].getPath());

     a.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

         var name = event.target.getAttribute('data-name');
         var path = event.target.getAttribute('data-path');

         loadProject(name, path);
     });

    div.appendChild(a)
    div.classList.add("project");
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it still doesn't seem to work. The `'data-name'` and `'data-path'` names are being set but the onclick still isn't being set. I think it may be a different issue though.